# Find average of multiple columns in a str dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to find the average of columns col3, col4, col5 in the below  given dataframe and add it as a new column called 'average' as shown in the required output dataframe using pandas.

Input dataframe:

```
di = {'col1': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'],
      'col2': ['123', None, '456', '789'],
      'col3': ['1', '2', '5',None], 
      'col4': ['4', '7', None, '8'], 
      'col5': ['9', None, '3', '8']}
df = pd.DataFrame(di, dtype=object)

   col1    col2   col3  col4  col5
0   abc     123      1     4     9
1   def    None      2     7  None
2   ghi     456      5  None     3
3   jkl     789   None     8     8
```

Required Output:

```
    col1   col2   col3  col4  col5  average
0   abc     123      1     4     9     4.66
1   def    None      2     7  None     4.5
2   ghi     456      5  None     3     4
3   jkl     789   None     8     8     8
```

Answer (score 3):

Select columns by names or by positions by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), convert to `float` because `None` is converted to `NaN` and last get `mean` per rows by `axis=1`:

```
cols = ['col3','col4','col5']
df['average'] = df[cols].astype(float).mean(axis=1)
```

```
df['average'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].astype(float).mean(axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5   average
0  abc   123     1     4     9  4.666667
1  def  None     2     7  None  4.500000
2  ghi   456     5  None     3  4.000000
3  jkl   789  None     8     8  8.000000
```

Comment: @SpghttCd - I think not, because `None`

Comment: @SpghttCd - Yes, if try it get `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Answer (score 0):

If not known columns (but i am skipping the first one because of desired output):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(di).fillna(pd.np.nan)
df['average']=df.apply(lambda row: pd.to_numeric(pd.Series(row.tolist()[2:]),errors='coerce').mean(),axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5   average
0  abc  123    1    4    9  4.666667
1  def  NaN    2    7  NaN  4.500000
2  ghi  456    5  NaN    3  4.000000
3  jkl  789  NaN    8    8  8.000000
```